# How to design an SMS SENDER using VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, sms

I'm new to VB .NET. I would like to design a sms sender application which could use internet connectivity to send messages to any mobile number. Should I use any messaging APIs? Where should I start?

Comment: There are lots of SMS related question in SO. Please search. I myself have answered many of them. Voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of companies that provide SMS gateway services and they often provide various forms of web and web service interfaces that are easy to integrate with.

I happen to work for one such company and I can tell you that interfacing directly with the mobile network operators is something that you most likely want to avoid.

I don't know which companies are worth partnering with 'round your bouts, but you might be able to ask some local operators who they partner with and get an overview of the market that way.